# Will marijuana affect my baby?

Tags: health, pregnancy, drugs

I'm about 3 weeks pregnant and I only just found out. During the week I had 2 draws of a joint but I didn't know I was pregnant. Will this harm my baby? I'm very nervous.

Comment: No, your baby is fine. Of course, you should not continue smoking or drinking, even moderately. I mean, years ago, women did both all the time throughout pregnancies, and most didn't have problems. Two draws at three weeks is pretty much guaranteed to be trivial compared to nine months of what everybody's exposed to pretty much constantly when participating in modern civilization.

Comment: Should be fine but seek medical advice from a professional is my advice.

Comment: I understand you are concerned, but you should talk to a medical professional -- we can't give medical advice over the internet.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an article from last year:

https://www.forbes.com/sites/tarahaelle/2016/09/09/so-does-marijuana-use-in-pregnancy-hurt-a-baby-or-not/?c=0&s=trending#2e9bf5101365

It basically says we don't have enough info to say conclusively whether marijuana negatively affects a gestating fetus. But, you can be pretty sure that the small amount you have had during this pregnancy will not have a negative effect, because the circumstance that MIGHT or MIGHT NOT have one is that of chronic use throughout pregnancy. I had some fondu before I realized I was pregnant with my first, and was freaking out about the alcohol in it, and had to be reminded that even meth addicts sometimes deliver perfectly healthy babies. Yes, it might possibly be slightly better for the baby if you didn't have those two drags, but the difference from that little will certainly not be noticeable or measurable. I'll reiterate Patrick87's statement about not smoking any MORE, though, because while the evidence about harm to the baby is highly inconclusive, the article claims that evidence of BENEFIT is non-existent. So far better safe than sorry.